# Installing installed app on a device with instant app

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

Please bear with me as I try to explain this weird issue I'm facing when installing the "installed app" over the "instant app".

**Steps to produce the problem:**

1. Install the instant app on the device running Android O.
2. Install the "installed app".

**Problem:**

1. The installed app does not show in the app drawer and if I go into device settings --> apps, I see the app as an instant app (with the lightning icon) but with the size of the installed app. So installed app is actually installed but behaves still like an instant app.
2. The instant app has only 1 activity and that is the 2nd activity of the installed app. So when I go into the installed app on first launch, I can't go past the 2nd activity as that activity behaves like an instant app i.e. `InstantApps.isInstantApp(activityContext)` returns true. So trying to go further in the app opens the play store page for the app.

If I install the installed app on a device without the instant app, it works fine.

The default url is defined for the 1 activity in the base feature and 2 activities in the installed app - launcher (home) and the 2nd activity (part of instant app).

What could be the issue here?

**Update**

I updated the installed app. Now I built the release version of the instant app for testing, and it opens the play store if I click on a feature which is only in the installed app, all good. But after I install the app, I face the same issue, it behaves like an instant app - no icon in the app drawer, lightning icon on the app icon in settings-->apps. How is this happening?

Comment: Do you run into this issue only with O preview build , or do you also see the same behavior on pre-O devices as well?  (current O preview is opp4.170623.014, developer.android.com/preview/download.html)

Comment: Only tried with O as my other devices don't support instant app yet, all countries aren't supported. Tried with opp3.170518.006.

Comment: Try to reproduce this issue with the current O preview build (opp4.170623.014), it is best to stay up-to-date with O preview builds https://developer.android.com/preview/release-notes.html.

If you still can see the same behavior with the latest O preview version, this might be a possible issue in this build. Can you file a bug, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: As a temporary workaround that worked for me, you can manually remove your instant-app (Settings > Apps > Select your instant app > Tap “Clear App”), and then install your installable app from PlayStore.

Comment: I will try with the latest O build. But the point is users won't clear the instant app before installing the installed app, that's why we haven't been able to update our instant app with the changes required for O.

Comment: I tried with the latest O preview build (opp4.170623.014) and the issue still remains. Posted the issue here --> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64467803.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your device/emulator already has the instant-app installed, you will run into problems like this if you install your installed-app from Android Studio. I’m not sure which Android Studio 3.0 Canary version you are on, but at the moment, there is something strange/broken with it (we’ll have to wait for an update).

Unfortunately, for now, you may need to manually install your installed-app with this adb cmd:

```
adb install -r -t --full <installed-app.apk>
```

This should properly override the instant-app with the installed-app.

Also see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63932235

Comment: Wow, thanks! Thankfully I didn't waste too much time on this. I'm using Canary 6.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the Instant Apps feature which is only meant for experiencing (getting an idea) of the app .If you want to test the application, install it without Instant Apps. Check the link for more information - https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html

Comment: What do you mean? This is not clear at all. And I have read the official documentation on Instant apps.